# Using Smarty or jQuery to calculate values, not sure which?

Tags: php, jquery, smarty

In Smarty I have the following values I fetch;

{$product.bean_bag_quantity_150} which returns 1 in this instance
{$product.bean_bag_quantity_300} and again returns 1

I also have

{$product.bean_bag_filling_150} and {$product.bean_bag_filling_300} which return either "N" or "Y".

What I need to do and not sure how  best to do this: I have conditions on {$product.bean_bag_filling_150} and the other.

Basically I need to do the following:

{$product.bean_bag_quantity_150} and {$product.bean_bag_quantity_300} contains the amount of filling, so if 150 has 0 will be none but if 150 returns 3 I want it to do 3 x 150 and same for the 300. If it returns 1 to do 1 x 300 and then add those together, but in some cases 150 might be 0 and 300 might be 1 so would just need to do 1 x 300.

So if enabled to get values at times them by either 150 or 300 whichever the quantity value is if its set and / if add the totals from 150 and 300 together.

Example:

If 150 is enabled and has a filling value of: 2
If 300 is disabled

Do 2 x 150 = 300

If 150 is enabled and value is 4
If 300 is enabled and value is 3

Do 4 x 150 = 600, 3 x 300 = 900 so both is 1500

etc... etc...

My attempt:

If either are enabled to Y

```
{if $product.bean_bag_filling_150 == "Y" || $product.bean_bag_filling_300 == "Y"}

                        {assign var="bb_qty_150_total" value=math equation="x * y" x=$product.bean_bag_quantity_150 y="150"}
                        {assign var="bb_qty_300_total" value=math equation="x * y" x=$product.bean_bag_quantity_300 y="300"}

                        <p>DEBUG: Total: {math equation="x + y" x=$bb_qty_150_total y=$bb_qty_300_total}</p>

                    {/if}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Worked out my solution and it is as follows:

```
{if $product.bean_bag_filling_150 == "Y" && $product.bean_bag_filling_300 == "Y"}

                    {math assign="bb_qty_150_total" equation="x * y" x=$product.bean_bag_quantity_150 y=150}
                    {math assign="bb_qty_300_total" equation="x * y" x=$product.bean_bag_quantity_300 y=300}

                    <p>DEBUG: Total: {math equation="x + y" x=$bb_qty_150_total y=$bb_qty_300_total}</p>

                {elseif $product.bean_bag_filling_150 == "Y" && $product.bean_bag_filling_300 == "N"}

                    <p>DEBUG: Total: {math equation="x * y" x=$product.bean_bag_quantity_150 y=150}</p>

                {elseif $product.bean_bag_filling_150 == "N" && $product.bean_bag_filling_300 == "Y"}

                    <p>DEBUG: Total: {math equation="x * y" x=$product.bean_bag_quantity_300 y=300}</p>

                {/if}
```

if anyone knows or a better solution please feel free to share :)